# Correct UserControl Usage?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I just started breaking up my GUI application into UserControls. I have a TabControl with a bunch of TagePages. Obviously my MainForm.cs file was filled up with tons of events and controls etc and it got very messy quick.

So a previous question gained me the insight of how to create a UserControl. I intend on creating a UserControl for each TabPage and I was wondering how I can interact with Components on the main form or other UserControls.

Here is an example of a TabPage that I have made using a UserControl, which needs to Enable or Disable a button depending which TabPage is currently selected. Is this proper usage or is there a better way?

```
public partial class TabDetails : UserControl
{
    private RequestForm fRequestForm;
    public TabDetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void CustomInitialization(RequestForm pRequestForm)
    {
        fRequestForm = pRequestForm;
        pRequestForm.TabControl_Main.SelectedIndexChanged += SelectedTabIndexChanged;
    }

    private void SelectedTabIndexChanged(object pSender, EventArgs pEvents)
    {
        fRequestForm.Button_SubmitRequest.Enabled = fRequestForm.TabControl_Main.SelectedTab != fRequestForm.Tab_Details;
    }
}
```

In the MainForm.cs constructor I call:

```
this.tab_Details1.CustomInitialization(this);
```

Comment: There is clearly an Event being used here, which makes your comment even more unhelpful. Try being a little more descriptive or providing more details around what you mean.

Comment: It's fine for your page to know specifics about your user control. However, your user control shouldn't have to care about anything on the page that contains it. Otherwise, you'll end up with user controls you can only use on one type of page.

Comment: @user1402923 - What if for this project it is acceptable that the UserControls are only going to be used on this one type of page?

Comment: @Tada - you don't really want to get into the mindset of 'I can make poor design decisions because it doesn't matter in this project'. What you want to do is make the most versatile and useable code you can. Besides, you never know if you might want to do a similar thing again in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't look like a good use of a user control. The user control should not decide how things in the form should behave when something is changed in the user control. A user control should be unaware of its container and should operate in any container.

The user control should notify the form that something has changed without telling what's the internal implementation and the form should decide what to do.

Example:
A user control named "NameUserControl" consists of TitleComboBox, FirstNameTextBox and LastNameTextBox. The user control wants to notify when one of the values has changed.

**Wrong Way:**

Create events:

TitleComboBox - SelectedIndexChanged.
FirstNameTextBox, LastNameTextBox - TextChanged.

The problems here:

1. You expose the internal controls behavior. What will happen if you want to change the TitleComboBox to TextBox? You'll have to change the event name and implementation.
2. You expose the fact that you use exactly 3 different controls. What will happen if you want to use the same text box for first and last name? You'll have to delete one event and change the name of the other.

**Good Way:**

Create only a single event: **NameChanged** and expose 1 property of FullName or three different properties for the values.

Either way the form subscribe to the event and decide what to do next.

Another thing to think about: the more you add more functionality to your user control, you either make it less reusable or you make its code more complex. For example, if you add validation inside the user control, you'll find one day that you need it without validation, so you'll add a property "bool ValidateData" or it will be so complicated that you'll need to build another control. One way to solve that is to build very small user controls, but combine them in one or more bigger user controls that fit all your current needs.

Comment: When you say "The user control should notify the form that something has changed without telling what's the internal implementation and the form should decide what to do." can you give me an example of this? Like would the Form subscribe to an Event within the UserControl?

Comment: Thanks for the example Amiram I think that put things into pretty good perspective for me.